# Why does the program end when I enter a number?

Tags: c++

I began programming on C++ some days ago and something is really getting me troubles:

whenever I enter the number, the program ends.

Code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int entry;

    cout << "Write a number: ";
    cin >> entry;
    cout << entry;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I need some help here so my programs could run right.

By right I mean to output the number after ending... but it just ends after I enter the number and press enter  It does not print it.

**UPDATE**:

For the sake of the ones who didn't understood what I was meaning (sorry for my english)

Ok let me explain.

-So the program is suposed to get the values from the keyboard right.

-I enter a number let´s say is 6, ok now I press enter.

-Alright now the number is supposed to be output on the screen, but this doesn´t happen because the program closes too fast.

But this was solved actually, by adding a second `cin.get();` or by adding a `cin.ignore();` after each data input petition.

Comment: Your program **is** running right. It'd doing exactly what you tell it to.

Comment: Quoting Brian Kernighan (I think): "what you see is *only* what you get".

Comment: What behaviour do you want? After you enter the number, what is your desired behaviour?

Comment: @AndréCaron, unless your compiler has bugs - not that this is the case here, but I've seen it in the past :)

Comment: but it just ends after I enter the number and press enter.
It does not print it

Comment: It might be that the reason the number is not printed is buffering. Usually, the stdout is line-buffered, so the number is printed to the output buffer, but that buffer isn't flushed, so it does not yet appear in the terminal. Then `cin.get()` reads the newline that's still in the input stream, and the program immediately exits, without flushing the output buffer. In that case, changing the printing line to `cout << entry << endl;` should make the number appear.

Comment: Thx but still having the issue.

Comment: @LeandroTheBest, can you give us more precise details of what does and does not happen. Please can you copy and paste the text from your terminal into your question?

Comment: Ok the problem was this, the program runs and it ask me to imput a value, then I imput the value and when I press enter the console closes. I fixed it by adding `cin.ignore();` after each `cin >> variable;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly improved version that might be closer to what you *wanted*:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::string line;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter an integer: ";

        if (!(std::getline(std::cin, line))) { return 1; /* error! */ }

        std::istringstream iss(line);
        if (iss >> n) { break; }
    }

    std::cout << "Thank you. You said: " << n
              << "\n\nPlease press Enter to quit.";

    std::getline(std::cin, line);
}
```

The error condition in the `getline` is triggered when the input stream is closed or otherwise terminated before another line could be read (e.g. if you hit Ctrl-D on the console). The token extraction into `n` fails until you enter a valid integer, and the loop will continue looping until this happens.

Comment: @Niko: `return 0;` is implicit at the end of `main`.

Comment: @NikoDrašković: This is C++, not C89.

Comment: You're right, I forgot, they built it into compilers because programmers are lazy

Comment: @NikoDrašković: Well... compilers do it because the *standard* says so. C99 prescribes that as well, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

[`get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) reads one and only one character from the stream, so it's perfectly normal that the program ends after you enter your number.

Have a look either at the [`std::basic_istream<>::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) method or, easier, [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) which doesn't require a dynamic buffer.

If you need more information about basic IO in C++, you can read the following documentation : [Basic Input/Output - C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

#### Update

Like stated in the comments, I missunderstood the question, I was initially thinking that only one digit was read into the variable.

After reading carefully again, I'm unable to understand what the problem is.

Comment: `std::basic_istream<>::getline()` requires use of a dynamic buffer, which is a terrible thing to recommend to a beginner. Prefer [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) instead.

Comment: Also, I think that `cin.get()` is returning immediately instead of blocking because the end of line character (at least, anything entered on the same line after a space should be there too) is still in the buffer because it is not consumed after a `istream::operator>>` call.

Comment: Surely it doesn't end after one digit. The line `cin >> entry` surely takes the integer? (Update: @AndréCaron has just said what I was going to say next. I think the program is correct already!)

Comment: I don't know if the program is "correct" in the sense wanter by the author, but I absolutely misread the code... After carefully reading it again, I must admit I didn't know what is wrong either.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is consume the newline that is left over after reading the integer.

This happens in java as well.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int entry;

    cout << "Write a number: ";
    cin >> entry;
    cout << entry;

    cin.get(); //Consume newline

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LeandroTheBest As good practice as any. Most of your programming is probably going to be dealing with GUI's anyways, where you only touch cout and cin for debugging.

Comment: @LeandroTheBest But, for completion's sake, Kerrek's answer is what you would use if you need to be able to recover from invalid input.

Comment: Nice, and what about cin.ignore(); its seems to work too if I place it after each (cin >> variable)

Answer (score -2):

The reason for this is youre using

```
cin.get();
return 0;
```

at the end of the program , the `cin.get()` reads the number you entered then goes straight to `return 0;` thus ending the program.

to stop this you can add an extra `cin.get();` before `return 0;`
or use

```
system("Pause");
```

before `return 0;` instead

Comment: cin.get() does not read the number. The number is read by `cin >> entry` and it appears to be correct. The program reads a number and prints it - this is correct isn't it?

Comment: @Aaron I think cin.get is just reading the newline in the buffer.

Comment: AFAIK, `system("pause");` is a DOS-only solution and only works on Windows.  Please do not recommend this without a warning.

Comment: Yes but it ends before printing it.

Comment: I don't think DOS-only solutions generally work on Windows... There's a built-in Windows API call for this; it's cleverly named `Sleep()`. But that's not really what you need here anyway.

Comment: And adding the extra cin.get(); helped